# what is the effect of bootstap resampling in bagging algorithm(ensemble learning)?

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, ensemble-learning, bagging

In ensemble learning with bagging, why is it important to do bootstrap resampling
(sampling with replacement) instead of just sub-sampling (sampling without
replacement)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not. Sampling with replacement is not required. Two issues come up when you use subsampling without replacement instead of the usual bootstrap samples: 
1. You must determine what sub-sample size to use, and
2. Out of bag observations are no longer created in the same way.

See Buja and Stuetzel, 2006, section 7 (entitled "Equivalence of Resampling With and Without Replacement in Bagging") here http://www.stat.washington.edu/wxs/Learning-papers/paper-bag.pdf for a reference.